# "The app "xxx" was not installed on the iPhone "xxx" because it is not compatible with this iPhone"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Im using x code 4.4.1 with cordova 1.7.0 , i created Ad Hoc IPA file and installed in iPad with iOS6 it works fine. Then i tried in iPhone 3gs with iOS 4.2.1 it shows error while installing - "The app "xxx" was not installed on the iPhone "xxx" because it is not compatible with this iPhone".
Deployment Target is 4.2 i used.

Comment: Have you checked if your distribution certificate includes the UDID of the iPhone 3GS?

Comment: yes i have checked the UDID

Comment: Have you looked at the console while installing the app? It might give a hint where the problem is.

Comment: i have the same issue, did you solve it @PraveenKumar ?

Answer (score 1):

you might created your project only for `iPad`. If you want to run your  `app` in both `iPhone` and `iPad`, you need to create your project as `Universal`. Check your `Targets`, in `Summary` tab whether `Devices` is set to `Universal` or `iPad`.